# EntraID : The code_verifier does not match the code_challenge supplied in the authorization request for PKCE

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-entra-id

We have a web app that used EntraID for OIDC. We use the web browser to loginto the web app , gets redirected to the EntraID authentication page and get authenticated and it works.

We are creating a new mobile app ( iOs ) and want to use the same  web app backend. We also want to use the EntraID for OIDC ( just like the browser) . We are using the [https://github.com/mobilityhouse/AppAuth-iOS-Without-Pkce library](https://github.com/mobilityhouse/AppAuth-iOS-Without-Pkce%C2%A0library) to implement OIDC with EntraID.
The library does not use PKCE ( as is in the name ). We can get the auth_code by making the API call to Microsoft EntraID, but when the backend tries to get the access_token , we get the error :

**The code_verifier does not match the code_challenge supplied in the authorization request for PKCE**

1. How is PKCE coming in picture when we are using no PKSE library ?
2. How can we get around this problem without any code change in the
   web backend ?
3. We have no issue when using browser, how can the mobile app work same as
   the browser ?

Searched on stackoverflow but did not find and good answers

Comment: I'm not very sure about my post, so pls just take a look and you might need to test by yourself.. Firstly, the web app you had now already integrated OIDC to let users sign in, so that when you want to get the resources from your mobile app, the web app should play the role like a web api, so that we also need to add AAD authorization scheme into your web app as well. We follow the official sample to get the moblie app to integrate AAD as well and make sure we could get user sign in and call graph api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/sample-v2-code?tabs=apptype#mobile

Comment: when we already able to sign in the mobile app and get access token to call graph api, let's change the scope to the one which is used to call web app(api). the document I shared also contains samples for web api and web app, you might check the startup file and you would see `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication` for api authorization and `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication` for web app in .net core